# Controlling Web Site Access via IP addresses

Tags: web-server, glassfish

Say I have a single physical server, running Windows 2003 Server.
Install two GalssFish application servers, one running on port 80, and the other port 8080.
Each GlassFish instance has an application deployed, so one application may be seen on port 80, and the other port 8080.

Is it possible to limit who may surf to the application running on port 8080 to only those users inside the company, and open up who may see the application running on port 80 to the whole internet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three ways to do this:

1. If these apps run under IIS you can use the Directory Security tab of the site proerties to restrict access to a specific subnet.
2. You can use Windows Firewall to restrict access to the respective ports to a specific subnet.
3. Only publish the app running on port 80 in your firewall for inbound access.

Comment: at this point, i just want to know if this is even possible in general...thanks